# GIT how to merge master into branch cloned with -single-branch

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I have a git repository, where master is the current version of the application and each customer has their own branch with their own customizations.

I have cloned each customers branch separately into a directory using --single-branch

My goal is to merge master into my branch. I have cloned the repo using following command:

```
git clone {{REPO_URL}} --single-branch my-branch --branch my-branch
```

Then I tried:

```
git fetch origin -- master

git merge master
```

Then I am getting this

> merge: master - not something we can merge

I know I could get around this by cloning entire repository, but is there anyway to work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add the url as another remote in your local repo.

Detail commands as below:

```
# In local my-branch
git remote add upstream <repo URL> -f
git merge upstream/master
```

Now your local `my-branch` contains the changes from `master` branch.

---

Update: to add remote only for `master` branch, you can use the command:

```
git remote add upstream <repo URL> -t master -f
```

If you already add the remote `upstream` with all branches, you can change it by:

```
git remote rm upstream
git remote add upstream <repo URL> -t master -f
```

Comment: This works, but it pulls all the branches, which is the thing I want to avoid. There is so much data in the repo and I don't want to have many duplicates of entire repo. That is the reason to use --single-branch in the first place. Is it possible to add upstream for master only?

Comment: @Firze Yes, it's possible. the `-t branchname` can achieve that. You can find the detail in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

You must:

- merge with `FETCH_HEAD`, or
- specify a destination reference name in your `git fetch` refspec, or
- adjust the `remote.origin.fetch` settings

or some combination of these items.  Depending on the combination used, you might want to fetch into `refs/remotes/origin/master` and run `git merge origin/master`, for instance.

#### Explanation

The key lies in *refspecs*.  A refspec, in its second-simplest form, is a pair of *references* separated by a colon, such as `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`.  The references can be abbreviated in some cases, e.g., `master:master`.  The name on the left is the *source*, and the name on the right is the *destination* (which the Git documentation abbreviates as <src> and <dst>).

Consider, then, your command:

> ```
> git fetch origin -- master
> ```

(The `--` is pointless here.)  The `git fetch` command treats `origin` as the name of the repository (so it looks up the URL associated with `origin`, and the `fetch =` refspecs associated with `origin`), and then treats `master` as a refspec, to combine with and partly override any previously-defined `fetch` refspecs.

When you make a `--single-branch` clone:

> ```
> git clone {{REPO_URL}} --single-branch --branch my-branch
> ```

this changes the `fetch` refspecs associated with the new clone.  (Note: the additional `my-branch` argument winds up being treated as a directory name.)  Running:

```
git config --list --local
```

will show you, among other items:

```
remote.origin.url=... whatever the URL expanded to...
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/my-branch:refs/remotes/origin/my-branch
```

This tells your Git that when it contacts the other Git at `origin`, the *default* action is to fetch *only* their branch `my-branch`, copying the result to your remote-tracking name `origin/my-branch`.

When you run `git fetch origin` with no additional arguments, your Git performs this default action.

Without `--single-branch`, Git would have used the default refspec, `fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.  This would direct Git to obtain *all* branches (all `refs/heads/` names), and copy them to remote-tracking names in your own repository.

When you give `git fetch origin` additional arguments, they are *refspecs*, just like this `fetch` setting.  You could, for instance, write:

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/normalbranch:refs/strangeref
```

which would direct your Git to copy their (local to them, and quite normal) branch `normalbranch` to a local reference in your own repository named `refs/strangeref`.

Now, I said above that a pair of names is the *second* simplest form of refspec.  You are using the simplest: a single name, `master`.  There is no colon; there is no second name.  This is still a valid refspec, but what it *means* is different in `git fetch` and `git push`.  Since we're only concerned with `git fetch`, let's [see what it means there](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html), which is:

> <refspec>
>
>   Specifies which refs to fetch and which local refs to update. ...
>
>   The format of a <refspec> parameter is an optional plus +, followed by the source <src>, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref <dst>. The colon can be omitted when <ds> is empty. ...
>
>   The remote ref that matches <src> is fetched, and if <dst> is not empty string, the local ref that matches it is fast-forwarded using <src>. ...

Since you don't have the `:` and destination, the <dst> part is empty, and no local reference is fast-forwarded.  (A leading plus sign `+` would tell Git to force-update the local reference even if fast-forwarding would fail, but you omit the local reference in the first place, so there's nothing for the `+` force flag to affect.)

What this means is that the commits `git fetch` brings over are recorded only in the old, backwards-compatible with Git version 1.5, `FETCH_HEAD` file.  So you'd have to `git merge FETCH_HEAD` to merge the commit whose ID is saved in `FETCH_HEAD`—the tip commit of the other Git's `master` branch.

#### Other alternatives

If you supply, on the command line, a destination refspec that does not exist:

```
git fetch origin master:refs/heads/tmpbranch
```

(which in this case creates a new local branch named `tmpbranch`), you could then supply that as the argument to `git merge`:

```
git merge tmpbranch
```

and then delete it:

```
git branch -D tmpbranch
```

so that you are ready for the next time (there's no `tmpbranch` lying around to make the `git fetch` potentially fail).

Or, you could use the force-flag to forcibly create-or-update your own `master` branch:

```
git fetch origin +master:master
```

(this relies on Git's automatic qualification turning `master` into `refs/heads/master`—if you're scripting, it's probably better to spell it out explictly; automatic qualification is for lazy humans, not for computers).  Then you can `git merge master`.

Note that this will overwrite your own local `master`, if you have created one and are using it.  For this reason, you might want instead to use a remote-tracking name:

```
git fetch origin +master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

after which you would run `git merge origin/master`.

Finally, you could direct your Git to always-by-default fetch the other Git's `master`:

```
git config --add remotes.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master'
```

Now you can just run:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

Fetching from `origin` will now, because there are two `remote.origin.fetch` settings, fetch *both* of the other Git's branches, `mybranch` *and* `master`, placing the fetched hash IDs into your remote-tracking names, `refs/remotes/origin/mybranch` and `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

(Compare this with the default refspec, `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, which tells your Git to fetch *all* branches and create or update a remote-tracking name whose name matches the branch name in the other Git.)

Comment: TLDR: `git fetch origin +master:refs/remotes/origin/master`. Read above for what it does and why. Thanks for all the detail @torek!

Answer (score 0):

I had cloned a single branch, that too with depth 1 (single commit):

```
git clone --depth 1 --single-branch branch_to_merge
```

now I wanted to merge this into a new branch "destn_branch" but hadn't cloned it in my local so I had to first fetch the branch again...

```
git fetch --depth 1 origin destn_branch:destn_branch
```

(I should have not done depth 1, but I was left with no choice :(, the commits were too many >_>)

now I ***could*** do

```
git checkout destn_branch
git merge branch_to_merge
```

but git said "are u crazy, those 2 branches are unrelated" (that is "uncommon history" something, I forgots the text)

so I one-upped git by re-running the above commands with a deeper depth so that they shared a common historical commit and git could understand that it can link the 2 branches from there on...
so, I re-ran the following commands and it worked:

```
// fetch 3 latest commits of branch_to_merge
git checkout branch_to_merge
git fetch --depth 3

// fetch 4 latest commits of destn_branch - this way one of the fetched commits is the same as in other branch's fetched commit
git fetch --depth 4 origin destn_branch:destn_branch

// now do a normal merge
git checkout destn_branch
git merge branch_to_merge
```

and they called me stingy for always doing depth-1 single-clone pulls -_-, now who is prudential >_>